# Display likes and dislikes flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app using flutter in which I need to display likes and I wish to display likes correct to 1 place of decimal but 999.9k is being displayed as 1000.0k when I use .toStringAsFixed() method, for some reason it shows a rounded-up value, can someone tell me how to display the number correctly.

```
Widget result;
    if (count == 0) {
      result = Text(
        'like',
        style: TextStyle(color: color),
      );
    } else if (count! >= 1000000) {
      result = Text(
        (count / 1000000.0).toStringAsFixed(1) + 'm',
        style: TextStyle(color: color),
      );
    } else
      result = Text(
        count >= 1000
            ? (count / pow(10, 3)).toStringAsFixed(1) + 'k'
            : text,
        style: TextStyle(color: color),
      );
    print(count!/1000);
    return result;
  },
```

Comment: The problems seems to be from the code where you get `999.9` , can you add your code?

Comment: Here is the code I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toStringAsFixed(0) will not show any decimals. simply calling toStringAsFixed() is rounding your values up.

Comment: So is there a way using which I can prevent that rounding up because if the number of likes is 9,999 I need to display it as 9.9k and not 10k?

Comment: You will need few If statements for example:
if( likes < 1000 ){
likes = likes;
it will give you 999 likes (if you have 1 to 999 likes)
no need to show K if this condition meets.
}
else if(likes > 1000 && likes < 100000) {
likes = likes / 1000;
 for example if you have 2222 likes it will give you 2.222 then you can do toStringasfixed(1) and it will give you 2.2K or if you have 99,999 it will give you 99.9K by adding .toStringAsFixed(1) and then add K in the string by this 
`${likes.toStringAsFixed(1)}` + 'K';
}
make more conditions if needed.

Comment: Let me know if you need more help? if the toStringAsFixed(0) was the basic solution to your first question please mark it is done.